# Image preview in ui-typeahead - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm making an application where a user can search through 10.000+ birnames using a typeahead.
Currently I have everything setup, without a preview, but I would like to add a little thumb next to the name to give a preview.

Seeing that I can't add 10.000 urls for each birdname into each document per bird in my database, I'd like to make a json request for the posibilies showing when typing.

I have set everything up accordingly:

A search input with a typeahead which collects all 10.000+ names from my database:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control search-input-nav" placeholder="Birdname" 
        autocomplete="off" ng-model="findBird" typeahead-no-results="noResults"
        uib-typeahead="bird for bird in birds | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
        typeahead-select-on-blur="true" 
        typeahead-template-url="/partials/model/birdTypeahead.html" 
        ng-enter="findBirdlist(findBird, noResults)">

        <div class="ErrorSearchBird" ng-if="noResults">
            <div class="errorTriangle"></div>
            <div class="errorText">Please pick a valid birdname</div>
        </div>
```

And the template made to show the image preview and name accordingly:

```
<div ng-controller="navCtrl">
    <a class="clickable">
      <img ng-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Little_tinamou.jpg" 
           width="16">
      <span ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

As you can see above, I would like to show the image of the specific bird, depending on the `match.label` right beside it.

Is there a way for me to check when new names are being shown and if so, make a json call and retrieve the image accordingly?
I've tried it using `ng-keydown` Though I don't know how to pass along the birdnames.

I hope this is a bit clear.. If it isn't, feel free to ask below and I'll try explaining it in another manner.

Comment: FYI, you will face performance & page lag issue, when binding gets increased to 2k+ records, please read up on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18381836/2435473)